# Unpivoting dates columns in large table in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unpivot

I have a table made of 16 columns and 30M records in BigQuery in the format below:

[image]

The data has 2 dates columns that I would like to put in into the same column date so that it would be possible to visualize how many events happened for each day.

Essentially, it would be having for each item and `itemtype` a line for the packaging date, few lines for the `statusdate` depending how many statuses occurred and all the columns in the tables.

Desired output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me which dates you'd like for which rows, but in concept, the easiest way to do what I think you're asking is UNIONs.

For example:

```
select itemtype, stages, <<date field (e.g. packagingdate)>> as dates
from mytable
where <<some condition (e.g. packagingdate is not null)>>
union all
select itemtype, stages, <<date field (e.g. signedoffdate)>> as dates
from mytable
where <<some condition (e.g. signedoffdate is not null)>>
```